# Girth of petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory

Why Girth of petersen graph is not 4?
here is my graph-:
[image]

Here 2  element subset $\left(i,j\right)$, $i,j$ belongs to $ {1,2,3,4,5} $ ,is disjoint to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a cycle, it's traversing the same edge back and forth. You could use the same approach to say that the girth is actually 2! Just walk from $(1,2)$ to $(3,4)$ and back...

Comment: but girth can't be 2...as cycle can't be of length 2

Comment: Yes, and your example is walking a cycle of length 2 twice.